# Using Spark dataframe how to control output file size when saving text or json to S3

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, rollingfilesink

I need to a way to control the output file size when saving `txt/json` to `S3` using `java/scala`.

e.g. I would like a rolling file size of 10 mb,
 how can i control this using dataframe code,

1. I have experimented with `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`. 
   This does not give accurate control. 
   e.g if I set `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=32MB`
   The output files are of size 33 mb.
2. Other option is to use reparition, `df.rdd.reparition(n)` 
   this will create n files.
   The values of n = size of inputfile/roll file size
   e.g input file size=200 mb, roll size=32 mb, 
   n =  200/32 = 7. Creates 6 files of size 32mb and 1 one 8 mb file.

Appreciate any thoughts about controlling the output file size.

Thanks

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: The first option does not do the job and the second is not efficient.